# Condition for while loop not working, unable to populate tableview cells

Tags: ios6, while-loop, uitableview

I'm a beginner to ios and am building my first app...so go easy on me :-)

I am trying to display the results from a web service in tableview cells. However my while loop condition is failing. I moved the nslog into the while loop and it clearly prints the objects in the array as you would expect. However there is something wrong when it ends I believe.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why it is failing?

Basically I'm trying to get 'Recipe name' and 'smallImageUrls; from the web service results and print that in a tableview cell.

I know my tableview cell wont print properly as is. I'll address that in a bit. Probably extract the urls into one array and then use that array to in the tableviewcell method.

Any assistance anyone can provide is greatly appreciated. I just find it strange as it is clearly going through the while loop without any issues. :-S

No real error message just:

self    SearchedYummlyViewController *  0x12b39570
matchesCount    int 40

in the left part of the pane at the bottom.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.searchYummlyRecipeResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.yummlyRecipesNSData options:nil error:nil];
    self.tempYummlyResultsMatches = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];  
    int matchesCount = 0;
    while([self.searchYummlyRecipeResults[@"matches"]objectAtIndex:matchesCount]){
        [self.tempYummlyRecipeMatch addObject:[[self.searchYummlyRecipeResults[@"matches"]objectAtIndex:matchesCount]objectForKey:@"recipeName"]];
        [self.tempYummlyRecipeMatch addObject:[[self.searchYummlyRecipeResults[@"matches"]objectAtIndex:matchesCount]objectForKey:@"smallImageUrls"]];   
        NSLog(@"tempYummlyRecipeMatch array's contents: %@", self.tempYummlyRecipeMatch);
        matchesCount++;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSString *recipeString = self.tempYummlyRecipeMatch[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = recipeString;

    //The below is code on how to add a image from a web service to a cell. I dont think that will work but my code cant make it down there yet so I'll tackle that after while loop issue.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.tempYummlyRecipeMatch[indexPath.row+1];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

    cell.imageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}
```

Example of the webservice output below:

```
Recipe List: {
    attribution =     {
        html = "<a href='http://www.yummly.com/recipes/onion-soup'>onion soup recipes</a> search powered by <img src='http://static.yummly.com/api-logo.png'/>";
        logo = "http://static.yummly.com/api-logo.png";
        text = "onion soup recipes: search powered by Yummly";
        url = "http://www.yummly.com/recipes/onion-soup";
    };
    criteria =     {
        allowedIngredients =         (
        );
        excludedIngredients =         (
        );
        facetFields =         (
        );
        maxResults = 6;
        requirePictures = 0;
        resultsToSkip = 0;
        terms =         (
            onion,
            soup
        );
    };
    facetCounts =     {
    };
    matches =     (
                {
            attributes =             {
            };
            flavors =             {
                bitter = "0.1666666666666667";
                meaty = "0.3333333333333333";
                piquant = 0;
                salty = "0.5";
                sour = "0.3333333333333333";
                sweet = "0.5";
            };
            id = "French-onion-soup-sandwiches-309090";
            ingredients =             (
                "olive oil",
                "sea salt",
                "fresh thyme leaves",
                "granulated sugar",
                "yellow onions",
                "unsalted butter",
                "beef broth",
                "cracked black pepper",
                "gruyere cheese",
                bread
            );
            rating = 0;
            recipeName = "French Onion Soup Sandwiches";
            smallImageUrls =             (
                "http://i.yummly.com/French-onion-soup-sandwiches-309090-273265.s.jpg"
            );
            sourceDisplayName = "Joy the Baker";
            totalTimeInSeconds = 0;
        },
                {
            attributes =             {
                course =                 (
                    "Main Dishes"
                );
            };
            flavors =             {
                bitter = 1;
                meaty = "0.1666666666666667";
                piquant = 0;
                salty = 1;
                sour = "0.1666666666666667";
                sweet = "0.3333333333333333";
            };
            id = "Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes";
            ingredients =             (
                "condensed cream of mushroom soup",
                "onion soup mix",
                "pot roast",
                water
            );
            rating = "4.69";
            recipeName = "Awesome Slow Cooker Pot Roast";
            smallImageUrls =             (
                "http://i2.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-2.s.png",
                "http://i.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-58919.s.png"
            );
            sourceDisplayName = AllRecipes;
            totalTimeInSeconds = 29400;
        },
                {
            attributes =             {
                course =                 (
                    Soups,
                    Appetizers
                );
                cuisine =                 (
                    French
                );
                holiday =                 (
                    Thanksgiving
                );
            };
            flavors =             {
                bitter = "0.1666666666666667";
                meaty = "0.1666666666666667";
                piquant = 0;
                salty = "0.1666666666666667";
                sour = "0.1666666666666667";
                sweet = "0.1666666666666667";
            };
            id = "French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364";
            ingredients =             (
                "stick butter",
                "french bread",
                "yellow onion",
                "low sodium chicken broth",
                "gruyere cheese",
                "minced garlic",
                "dry white wine",
                "worcestershire sauce",
                "beef broth"
            );
            rating = 0;
            recipeName = "French Onion Soup";
            smallImageUrls =             (
                "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-1512.s.jpg",
                "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-1199.s.jpg",
                "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-220.s.jpg"
            );
            sourceDisplayName = "The Pioneer Woman";
            totalTimeInSeconds = 0;
        },
                {
            attributes =             {
                course =                 (
                    Soups
                );
            };
            flavors = "<null>";
            id = "Curried-sweet-potato-soup-333086";
            ingredients =             (
                broth,
                salt,
                "sweet potatoes",
                "lite coconut milk",
                onion,
                "coconut oil",
                "curry powder",
                garlic,
                spinach,
                lime,
                "chopped cilantro",
                "red pepper flakes",
                "brown sugar",
                peas
            );
            rating = 0;
            recipeName = "Curried Sweet Potato Soup";
            smallImageUrls =             (
                "http://i.yummly.com/Curried-sweet-potato-soup-333086-295006.s.jpg"
            );
            sourceDisplayName = "Camille Styles";
            totalTimeInSeconds = 0;
        },
                {
            attributes =             {
            };
            flavors = "<null>";
            id = "French-onion-soup-grilled-cheese-308496";
            ingredients =             (
                "unsalted butter",
                "kosher salt",
                "sweet onions",
                "unsalted beef stock",
                pepper,
                "gruyere cheese",
                "dry sherry",
                "italian bread",
                "fresh thyme"
            );
            rating = 0;
            recipeName = "French Onion Soup Grilled Cheese";
            smallImageUrls =             (
                "http://i.yummly.com/French-onion-soup-grilled-cheese-308496-272505.s.jpg"
            );
            sourceDisplayName = "The Kitchn";
            totalTimeInSeconds = 0;
        },
                {
            attributes =             {
            };
            flavors =             {
                bitter = 1;
                meaty = 1;
                piquant = 0;
                salty = 1;
                sour = 1;
                sweet = "0.8333333333333334";
            };
            id = "Vidalia-onion-soup-with-wild-rice-and-blue-cheese-305366";
            ingredients =             (
                "vidalia onions",
                "chicken stock",
                herb,
                pepper,
                "wild rice",
                "unsalted butter",
                baguette,
                salt,
                "extra virgin olive oil",
                other
            );
            rating = 0;
            recipeName = "Vidalia Onion Soup with Wild Rice and Blue Cheese";
            smallImageUrls =             (
                "http://i.yummly.com/Vidalia-onion-soup-with-wild-rice-and-blue-cheese-305366-268824.s.jpg"
            );
            sourceDisplayName = "Smitten Kitchen";
            totalTimeInSeconds = 0;
        },
```

Example of tempYummlyRecipeResults nslog

```
tempYummlyRecipeMatch array's contents: (
    "French Onion Soup Sandwiches",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-onion-soup-sandwiches-309090-273265.s.jpg"
    )
)
2013-02-27 22:13:34.334 CustomTableView[435:11303] tempYummlyRecipeMatch array's contents: (
    "French Onion Soup Sandwiches",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-onion-soup-sandwiches-309090-273265.s.jpg"
    ),
    "Awesome Slow Cooker Pot Roast",
        (
        "http://i2.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-2.s.png",
        "http://i.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-58919.s.png"
    )
)
2013-02-27 22:13:34.335 CustomTableView[435:11303] tempYummlyRecipeMatch array's contents: (
    "French Onion Soup Sandwiches",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-onion-soup-sandwiches-309090-273265.s.jpg"
    ),
    "Awesome Slow Cooker Pot Roast",
        (
        "http://i2.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-2.s.png",
        "http://i.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-58919.s.png"
    ),
    "French Onion Soup",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-1512.s.jpg",
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-1199.s.jpg",
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-220.s.jpg"
    )
)
2013-02-27 22:13:34.335 CustomTableView[435:11303] tempYummlyRecipeMatch array's contents: (
    "French Onion Soup Sandwiches",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-onion-soup-sandwiches-309090-273265.s.jpg"
    ),
    "Awesome Slow Cooker Pot Roast",
        (
        "http://i2.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-2.s.png",
        "http://i.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-58919.s.png"
    ),
    "French Onion Soup",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-1512.s.jpg",
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-1199.s.jpg",
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-220.s.jpg"
    ),
    "Curried Sweet Potato Soup",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/Curried-sweet-potato-soup-333086-295006.s.jpg"
    )
)
2013-02-27 22:13:34.335 CustomTableView[435:11303] tempYummlyRecipeMatch array's contents: (
    "French Onion Soup Sandwiches",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-onion-soup-sandwiches-309090-273265.s.jpg"
    ),
    "Awesome Slow Cooker Pot Roast",
        (
        "http://i2.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-2.s.png",
        "http://i.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-58919.s.png"
    ),
    "French Onion Soup",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-1512.s.jpg",
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-1199.s.jpg",
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-220.s.jpg"
    ),
    "Curried Sweet Potato Soup",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/Curried-sweet-potato-soup-333086-295006.s.jpg"
    ),
    "French Onion Soup Grilled Cheese",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-onion-soup-grilled-cheese-308496-272505.s.jpg"
    )
)
2013-02-27 22:13:34.335 CustomTableView[435:11303] tempYummlyRecipeMatch array's contents: (
    "French Onion Soup Sandwiches",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-onion-soup-sandwiches-309090-273265.s.jpg"
    ),
    "Awesome Slow Cooker Pot Roast",
        (
        "http://i2.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-2.s.png",
        "http://i.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-58919.s.png"
    ),
    "French Onion Soup",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-1512.s.jpg",
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-1199.s.jpg",
        "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-220.s.jpg"
    ),
    "Curried Sweet Potato Soup",
        (
        "http://i.yummly.com/Curried-sweet-potato-soup-333086-295006.s.jpg"
    ),
    "French Onion Soup Grilled Cheese",
        (
        "http://i.yu
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `connectionDidFinishLoading`, you should reload your table view.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Just updating your array does not instantly update your table view.

**EDIT:** You are right, your `while` loop condition is incorrect. Currently, it only checks if the object at index `matchesCount` is not `nil` (somewhat similar to `while(object)` or `while(object != nil)`). I think what you are looking for is if the number of objects in the array is greater than `matchesCount` so as to prevent an array index out of bounds exception. To do so, you need to use `while([self.searchYummlyRecipeResults[@"matches"] count] > matchesCount)`.

Comment: Hi neilvillareal - Thanks for the response. However I feel that there is something wrong with the actual statement in the 'while loop'. I changed the loop to while (matchesCount < 10). I can now successfully get through the while loop. The recipe names are shown in the tableview cells. So I would guess that there is something wrong with the actual expression in the while loop. I left it out but I am reloading the tableview. Thats fine. I omitted that.

Comment: @Anthony I just edited my answer. Could you try if that solves your question?